# Elasticsearch - select document based on value in another document

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child, elasticsearch-5

I have a parent document (ex: "Parent") which has two types of child documents: "Child 1" and "Child 2". I want to select child 2 documents which satisfy condition based on a value of field in child 1. Is it possible in ElasticSearch? If not, how can I approach this?

I am using ElasticSearch 5.5

Comment: As far as I can tell this is a join query which is not supported in ES. And it's not even a parent-child query, it uses child-child information so I don't think you can solve this.

Comment: Well child-child is possible in ES: you can have has_child nested withing has_parent, so that would not be a blocker. But the join part feels like a blocker. I am just wondering if there is some other way I can solve this problem, without doing joins

Answer (score 0):

You can use siren join plugin which filters documents of one source based on another source based on a common field.

Here is the link to it https://github.com/sirensolutions/siren-join

As mentioned in this link that this has been moved in vanguard for your version